# How can I add 'product' or 'category' as dimension to Google Analytics custom reports?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

It is kinda wired, but I can not find `product` or `category` (product list) as a dimension in my custom reports. Nor can I find any other word that fits to these dimensions.

[image: custom report]

**How can I add product (name) or category (product list name) to my custom reports?**

**Note:** When I am in Conversions -> eCommerce -> Product Performance and click on Customize, then I see these dimensions in this customized report. But I need them in a new report/other report as well.

**Note 2:** When I start a new custom report, I can use `Product` as dimension. But as soon as I do this and create a new tab in this report, I can not use `Product List Category`. **Why does Google Analytics delimit my selection when I am in a new tab (same report)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each custom report is based on the same data - the tabs are meant to merely display the data in a different way.

To use different data, you need to create a new report. You will not be able to do it in a new tab.

Edit:

[This link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) lists how different dimensions and metrics work together and exclude each other, which is helpful in making your reports work.

Comment: Yeah, I see - [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) you can see when certain data excludes other data. If you could use this link and explanation in your answer, I would like to mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the link, @Jurik, I've just added it.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a field "Product revenue" under Ecommerce in metric group

Then you should be able to choose what you like in dimension drilldown. But you are not able to categorize for article in here.

Product revenue  -> Produktumsatz in german  I dont know if I translated correctly.

There are also the following to choose from. Please try alse these
Product revenue in local currency  -> Produktumsatz in landeswährung
Product revenue per sale -> Produktumsatz je kauf
Product list ->  Produktliste ctr

Comment: Yes, I figured out when I create a new custom report, I can chose "Product" as dimension. But as soon as I save something else in this report, I can not chose it anymore. Seems to be a bug in Google Analytics.

Comment: what exactly are you saving? maybe the product optioin is not available for it

Comment: Yes, I guess that is the problem. But even when I delete in this report all dimensions and metrics, product does not show up. I have to open a complete new report and that is wired.

Comment: Does your ecommerce tracking already has gathered data on this?

Comment: Yes, it has. I am quite confident with Google Analytic Reports, it just confused me that product was not avaible, even when no metric and dimension was selected.